# CSS overflow:hidden bug

Tags: css, overflow

I am relying on the CSS property `overflow:hidden` to contain 3 nested & floated `div`s.  The `overflow:hidden` is applied to the parent `div` of this html.

When I don't use `overflow:hidden` my last `div` is out of place within a line of floated `div`s, but when I do use `overflow:hidden` the entire `div` structure moves downwards.

Hopefully someone can understand what I mean by the text above, but in-case not I'll provide CSS code too.

**CSS:**

```
#header {
  display: block;
  width: 590px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #336699;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;

  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-left-wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 150px; height: 50px;
  background: #ff0000;
}
.header-input-wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 300px; height: 50px;
  background: #00ff00;
}
.header-right-wrapper {
  float: right;
  width: 140px; height: 50px;
  background: #ff0000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

To clarify, for some reason when I apply `overflow:hidden` to `.header-right-wrapper`, the entire header moves down as if I just applied a `margin` or `position`.  Any help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you showed us said HTML

Comment: Here is the fiddle.net (http://jsfiddle.net/ZETus/)

Comment: Is all the code in the fiddle necessary to demonstrate the problem? A minimal example would be nice.

Comment: Well, the problem I'm having is occuring within a popup div.  That is why I added JavaScript to jsfiddle.  I also added html because someone wanted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.header-right-wrapper is dropping because, as a floated element, it needs to clear something else on the page (.close). When you give #header {overflow: hidden} it's forced to contain its children, at least to the point that it reaches its {height}, including that floated div. Therefore it moves down. The problem is not your markup related to #header, but the Lightbox layout as a whole. Here's one fix:

```
.close {margin-bottom: -100px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZETus/4/

Another approach would be to take .close out of the flow using absolute positioning, so that the float doesn't have to clear it:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZETus/5/

```
.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  It worked.  But could you explain why it worked (I'm not very good with layouts).  To me, it would seem that adding margin-bottom to .close would push #header even further down.

Comment: Notice that it's a negative margin, which allows elements below to intrude upon its space. Please remember to mark your accepted answer.